# I am trying to copy columns from one workbook to a master with fixed headings

Tags: excel, vba

OK, I think I have read every option that comes up and not quite getting the answer from those which have already been answered - please forgive me if it has been answered and I'm just being special.

WHat I am looking to do is the following:

From a master WorkBook with fixed (62) headings be able to run a Macro/VBA which will enable me to open a file (.csv) grab the columns from this file and place them under the respective header on the master sheet.

The .csv file will definitely have the column header to match the main file but it may not be in the same sequence.

Your help would be gratefully appreciated.

Nick

This is the code I have help with so far...

```
Sub CopyCSV()

'' Find out how many rows are on the CSV sheet
LRCSV = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'' Find out how many columns are on the Data sheet
LCData = Sheet2.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For x = 2 To LRCSV

'' Find the last row and add one to get the first blank row
LRData = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

Sheet2.Activate

'' Finds the columns by the headers

If FirstN = "" Then
    For y = 1 To LCData
        If Cells(1, y).Value = "First Name" Then FirstN = y
        If Cells(1, y).Value = "Surname" Then SurN = y
        If Cells(1, y).Value = "Email" Then Email = y
        If Cells(1, y).Value = "Telephone Number" Then TelN = y
    Next y
End If

Sheet1.Activate

Sheet2.Cells(LRData, FirstN).Value = Sheet1.Cells(x, "A").Value
Sheet2.Cells(LRData, SurN).Value = Sheet1.Cells(x, "B").Value
Sheet2.Cells(LRData, Email).Value = Sheet1.Cells(x, "C").Value
Sheet2.Cells(LRData, TelN).Value = Sheet1.Cells(x, "D").Value

Next x

End Sub
```

Its the find by columns section I'm struggling with...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the [code efforts you've made?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). This will go a long way in helping us help you.

Comment: Hi Scott - Have eddited and added the code I've got so far.

Answer (score 1):

Nick, I've taken a bit of a different approach to solve the issue you are facing. However, I think it will be a cleaner approach and one that is easier to understand.

This code assumes you already have the CSV open. Also, there are many placeholders I filled in for objects. Change to suit your needs. I've also commented a bit where I thought it would help you understand the code more fully.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColumns()

'set the variables needed
Dim wkbMain As Workbook, wkbCopy As Workbook
Dim wksMain As Worksheet, wksCopy As Worksheet

Set wkbMain = Workbooks("Master.xlsm")
Set wkbCopy = Workbooks("email - pws a.csv")

Set wksMain = wkbMain.Sheets("Master")
Set wksCopy = wkbCopy.Sheets(1) 'csv files will only ever have 1 sheet

With wksMain

    'capture the header row in the master sheet
    Dim rngFind As Range, cel As Range
    Set rngFind = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Rows(1)) 'assumes contigous header rows
    'Set rngFind = .Range(.Range("A1"),.Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToRight) ' could use this as well if your data starts in cell A1

    For Each cel In rngFind 'loop through each header in the row

      Dim rngCopy As Range

      With wksCopy

        Set rngCopy = .Rows(1).Find(cel, after:=.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues) 'find the header name in the CSV sheet
        'now copy the entire column (minus the header row)
        Set rngCopy = .Range(rngCopy.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Column).End(xlUp))
        rngCopy.Copy Destination:=wksMain.Cells(2, cel.Column) 'paste it to the matching header in the main sheet

      End With

    Next

End With 'this was missing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott - I get a compile error "Syntax Error" at Set rngCopy = wksCopy.Range...

Is it something I've not done?

Cheers

Nick

Comment: @NICKBRIDGEN -> I left out a parenthesis. Please try now. (I've edited the post).

Comment: Hi Scott - So I get an Unexpected End With error, I've tried to work out why but my VBA knowledge just isnt there yet.

Have got VBA for Dummies and am only just getting to the important bits!!!

Comment: And I cant type a simple error message. Sorry it says Compile Error: Expected End With

Comment: Hi nick there is a missing `end with` statement between next and end sub, I've taken the liberty to correct it in the answer. But it is under peer review

Comment: @Pynner -> thanks for that. That's what I get for coding write in the answer box!

Comment: @NICKBRIDGEN -> see the edit by Pynner. Sorry about that. Laziness on my part.

Comment: Guys - Thanks so much for your help on this.. but...

I've made the changes (and had to change my sheet names as I hadn't got them the same as the code) it runs through without any errors but doesn't copy the data from CSV to the MASTER.

I've gone through the steps and (to me) looks perfect. -Nick

Comment: @NICKBRIDGEN -> i've made an edit to the `Copy` method. See if that works. If not, post back. Can't see why it wouldn't work from here. Also, you can also change the code to fit your sheet / workbook names. I alluded to such in the beginning of the post.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman -> Still comes up blank. Runs without any errors though. Sorry to be a pain Scott!
Re the changes - I did take on board what you had said but thought I would follow what you had coded first and get it working then make changes after.
Will have a play in the mean time and see if I can work it out.

Comment: @NICKBRIDGEN -> did you step through the code (using F8 in the debugger) and see what each line is doing, making sure it behaves the way you would expect?

Comment: Should `rngCopy.copy` not be `rngCopy.paste` at the end?

Comment: @Pynner -No, it should not. I use the `Copy` method, with the `Destination` argument to paste the data.

Comment: Cool, I've never used that function before.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman No did not F8 will try that now and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman ran with F8 and it steps through all ok. Have tried with the sheets on each being identical as well. Have tried with the source file being .csv & xlsx but both do the same.Going to try simplifying the headers and see

Comment: @NICKBRIDGEN -> if you can post two sample files of your csv and your main file, I can try it on my end.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman -> I thought that it may be an Excel 2013 issue but have just tried to it on 2010 and does the same thing. How do I add the files for you to look at?

Comment: @NICKBRIDGEN -> you can use a site like [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com) and then post the link(s) to the file(s).

Comment: @NICKBRIDGEN -> it may take me some time to get to this, I am very busy with work today

Comment: @NICKBRIDGEN -> okay. I got it. I basically had to change the way I was defining `rngFind` and also add a `after` argument to the find. Now it should work like a charm, or at least it did for me.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman You're going to hate me! Set rngCopy = .Range(rngCopy.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Column).End(xlUp))
        rngCopy.Copy Destination:=wksMain.Cells(2, cel.Column) returns an error - Object Variable or Block with variable missing.

Comment: @NICKBRIDGEN -> use the code I edited into my answer yesterday. it should work flawlessly.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks Scott! (Still has the error as above but am going to see if I can figure it out!) 
Will PM you on something else.